Google Image Search - link to specific part of page
I have a longer webpage with many images on it. Google is indexing those images.
Currently, when I get to my webpage via Google Image Search, I'm taken to the top of the page. This is not very user friendly as the image may be a long ways down the page.
Is there a way to get Google to link directly to the relevant part of the webpage?
